# Why setText('') in onPress dont works and how to clear TextInput?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I started coding on react native and I dont understand at all why I hook dont work here.
This is part of my code that dont work:

```
const notes = [];

const CustomTextInput = () => {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState('')



const onPress = e => {
    var key = e.nativeEvent.key
    if (key === "Enter" && last_press_key === "Enter"){
      last_press_key = ""
      notes.push(text)
      setText("")
      alert(notes)
    }
    else {
      last_press_key = key
    }
  }

  onTextChange = (e) => {
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadFont() {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'custom-font': require('./assets/fonts/MonospaceRegular.ttf'),
      });

      setFontLoaded(true);
    }

    loadFont();
  }, []);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return <TextInput>Loading...</TextInput>;
  }

  return (
    <TextInput multiline = {true}
    value = {text}
    onKeyPress={(e) => onPress(e)}
    style={{ ...props.style, fontFamily: 'custom-font', }}
    onChangeText={(text)=> setText(text)}
    >
      {props.children}
    </TextInput>
  );
};
```

I want to add input text to array and delete it from screen on double click Enter, i use hooks,  but that dont work.

Comment: Sidenote: your `onPress` is already an arrow function. You don't need to wrap it in a second arrow function, it already has the correct execution context baked in, just use `onKeyPress={onPress}`. More importantly: don't use `var`, use `let` for mutable and `const` for immutable variables, and _don't use alert_, use the normal console api (e.g. `console.log`, `console.error` etc). Alert _blocks the entire page thread_ and can only log strings, get in the habit of using console logging with your dev tools open.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared last_press_key as a local variable to onPress. This means it will always be `undefined` when called.

It would be best to store last_press_key as component state so it's stored between calls.

```
const notes = [];

const CustomTextInput = () => {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  const [lastKey, setLastKey] = useState('')



const onPress = e => {
    var key = e.nativeEvent.key
    if (key === "Enter" && lastKey === "Enter"){
      setLastKey("")
      notes.push(text)
      setText("")
      alert(notes)
    }
    else {
      setLastKey(key)
    }
  }

  onTextChange = (e) => {
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadFont() {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'custom-font': require('./assets/fonts/MonospaceRegular.ttf'),
      });

      setFontLoaded(true);
    }

    loadFont();
  }, []);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return <TextInput>Loading...</TextInput>;
  }

  return (
    <TextInput multiline = {true}
    value = {text}
    onKeyPress={(e) => onPress(e)}
    style={{ ...props.style, fontFamily: 'custom-font', }}
    onChangeText={(text)=> setText(text)}
    >
      {props.children}
    </TextInput>
  );
};
```